# Remove File Extensions from Song Titles in jPlayer Playlist

Tags: php, jplayer

Hello and thank you in advance! I'm a photographer and musician who also understands CSS, but java and php... not so much.

I'm using code from the legacy jPlayer to build a music site. Everything works as it should, but I can't figure how to remove the file extensions from the song titles.

Screenshot: [Playlist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RdOUy.jpg)

As far as I can tell, this is the code that generates the playlist. I'm using the **filename only** option, near the bottom:

```
<?php
        asort($fileinfo);
        foreach ($fileinfo as $value) {
        
            if($relMusicDir=='./') $showfrom='[from '.$value['from'].']<br /> ';
        
            if($useID3==TRUE){
                //WORKS
                //echo$comma.'{name:"'.$value['artist'].' - '.$value['title'].'",mp3:"'.$relMusicDir.$value['filename'].'"}';
                
                //TRY
                
                //if artist or title are empty, use filename
                if( (!isset($value['artist'])) AND (!isset($value['title'])) )
                    echo$comma.'{name:"'.$showfrom.$value['filename'].'",flac:"'.$value['path'].'"}';
                
                //skip, if filename or path are empty
                else if( (isset($value['filename'])) OR (isset($value['path'])) ){
                    echo$comma.'{name:"'.$showfrom.$value['artist'].' - '.$value['title'].'",flac:"'.$value['path'].'"}';
                }
                
                    
            }
            
            else //assume filename only
                //WORKS
                //echo$comma.'{name:"'.$value.'",mp3:"'.$relMusicDir.$value.'"}';
                
                //TRY
                echo$comma.'{name:"'.$showfrom.$value['fn'].'",flac:"'.$value['path'].'"}';
            
            $comma=','."\n\t\t";
        }
        
        ?>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. At "assume filename only," I modified the last few lines of code like this:

```
else //assume filename only
            //WORKS
            //echo$comma.'{name:"'.$value.'",mp3:"'.$relMusicDir.$value.'"}';
            
            //TRY
            $withoutExt = preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '', $value['fn']);
            echo$comma.'{name:"'.$withoutExt.'",flac:"'.$value['path'].'"}';
        
        $comma=','."\n\t\t";
```